# Overwriting termstoremanager.css?

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, branding, term-store

I have tried all solutions to overwrite the TmtTree class in the termstoremanager.css - to no avail (Can't overwrite that css right?). So I added the class to my core.css  to overwrite the default black font color:

```
.TmtTree {
    font-size: 8pt;
    margin: auto;
    **color: #ffffff!important;**
}
```

But it's not working at all!

Our theme's background is dark - so termstore is using the default black font  - which is not working on the dark background theme.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it isn't working? And by that I mean, I think it is probably doing what you're asking it to do, but not what you **want** it to do.

I'm using my browser debugger to look at the structure of the taxonomy picker and the .TmtTree is applied to the top level `<ul>`. If I change the color on that element in the debugger I don't notice any change. I think there are additional inheritances for the children elements of the list.

If I add a class definition like this which targets all children of the .
.TmtTree I do see the change.

```
.TmtTree * {
   color: white!important;
}
```

Of course that might have some unintended consequences. So you might want to make something more targeted like `.TmtTree>ul>li` or something. Not sure exactly.